# Há diferença entre "variavelX: function(){...}" e "variavelX = function(){...}"?

Tags: javascript

```
Exemplo.prototype = {
    minhaFuncao: function() {
        this.variavelX++;
    }
}
```

Eu encontrei este sinal `:` aparentemente agindo como um sinal de atribuição (`=`), mas não tenho certeza se ele age como um sinal de atribuição ou se ele age de uma forma diferente por baixo dos panos.

Há alguma diferença entre `minhaFuncao: function(){...}` e `var minhaFuncao = function(){...}`?

Comment: Oi Lucas, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Sua questão não ficou muito clara para mim, você poderia por favor editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes bem como um possível exemplo de código?

Comment: Editei a pergunta rs

Comment: Perfeito. Dei uma complementada para tentar ajudar, fique a vontade para corrigir minha edição.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var minhaFuncao = function(){...}
```

Você pode utilizar em qualquer parte do teu código, e independente do lugar que você declará-la, `minhaFuncao` será de escopo global.

Já

```
minhaFuncao: function(){...}
```

como você pode ver, está no prototype de `Exemplo`, então basicamente você utiliza esta forma para definição e atribuição de propriedades dentro de objetos, mantendo-se o escopo do mesmo, e para acessá-la você utilizará uma instância de `Exemplo.`

```
var ex = new Exemplo();
ex.minhaFuncao();
```